# Laravel Relation with a variable "Model" Type combined into one relation

Tags: laravel, relationship

I need the following setup:

- `Course`
- --> hasMany "`Chapters`"
- ----> hasMany "`Modules`"

So far so good, if it would be *that* easy. But the so called "Module" could either be:

- `Lesson::class` or a
- `Quiz::class`

and the either/or models must be in a special order, so it could be that:

1. `Lesson` How to buy recipients
2. `Lesson` How to cook pancakes
3. `Quiz` Do you know the receipt of a pancake?
4. `Lesson` How to serve the dinner
5. `Lesson` How to hold the fork and the knive
6. `Quiz` Do you know how to eat a pancake?

So what I need in general is a relationship:

```php
class Course {
  public function items() {
    // now there comes pseudo code
    return hasMany Lesson::class AND/OR Quiz::class -> orderBy('position')
  }
}
```

but HOW :grin:.... I am totally lost how to do the "create" architecture, how to retrieve the models etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need a polymorphic relationship. A relationship that can be morphed into either a lesson or a quiz.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

```
courses
   id - int
   title - string
   module_id - int 
   module_type - string

lessons
   id - int
   title - int

quiz
   id - int
   title - int
```

You will only need to have one relation call `modules()` which can be defined likes this

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

So calling  `Course::find(1)->modules` will give you a collection of both Lesson and Quiz. The classes is stored in the `module_type` field and the id in `module_id` so Laravel will know which class to cast the record to.

Comment: the example "comments" is attached either to a "post" or to a "video". But I need a "video" or a "post" attached to a "comment". To be more precised: Something like a "contentable" relationship, that could decide: is the content() a "quiz" or a "lesson"

Comment: Show him the code for that a little vague just to link to the documentation

Comment: But none of the basic laravel relations could deal with my situation.. 

`Course->contents()` returns a list constisting of Lesson::class AND Quiz::class, so it results in e.g.

1. Lesson (`position: 1`, type: Lesson::class)
2. Lesson (`position: 2`, type: Lesson::class)
3. Lesson (`position: 3`, type: Lesson::class)
4. Quiz (`position: 4`, type: Quiz::class)
5. Lesson (`position: 5`, type: Lesson::class)

Comment: @AndreasPabst you are honestly describing what polymorphic will do for you. You can make a relation in your Course model call `modules()` which will return a list of both chapters and quizzes.

Comment: Hmm.. but then I have two relationships `lessons()` and `quizzes()` but they are not combined into one `contents()`. Do you know what I try to explain?

Comment: You will only need one relationship to pull both lessons and quizzes. I added more info to the answer. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: thank you for updating your answer! But in your example (with this structure) it's only possible to define *one* single model in courses. I think your example wont work and - I am very sorry - I still dont get it completely. I at least need a morphToMany relationship with an morphTo() inverse right?

Comment: My apologies. You are correct in that you will need the many-to-many variant where the pivot table will have `course_id, module_id, module_type` as the fields. You don't have to accept the answer as it Is not 100% accurate. Hopefully, I was able to guide you in the right direction and you can find a solution with a polymorphic relation.